# Spring Security - inMemoryAuthentication doesn't get updated while application is running

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I try to configure my app's security using Spring Security - and in works. However, I found out that if there's changes on the credentials, let say the role have been changed, it doesn't reflect while the application is running. It will only get reflected when I restart the application again. Below is my code:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {   
          ArrayList<AUTH_User> auList = AUTH_Login.GetUserDetails();
          for(AUTH_User au : auList){
          auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(au.userName).password(au.password).roles(au.role);
          }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way for me to force refresh `inMemoryAuthentication` ? I'm thinking of refresh the whole Spring Security configuration - if it's possible. Thanks in advance.